# Swift - Swipe to delete (without the delete button) in a static UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I want to implement a feature, to swipe the whole table cell away using Swift 3.0. Like how you can swipe to delete in iOS 10's Mail app.

Important to note that, I don't mean swipe to show a delete button, and then handle the deletion. I mean users can swipe from right to left across the screen to delete. (Also note that the tableView is static, not dynamic)

Do I have to implement a UISwipleGestureRecognizer for that?

Comment: yes you can use swipegesture on perticular cell of tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)` as you would for a table with dynamic content.

However, in a table with static content you cannot insert or delete rows. With the table being static, the rows are supposed to stay. What you can do is update your swiped row to reflect the deleted status.

For example: In my app I am using the built-in swipe gesture to reset a setting. The user swipes the row (static content), taps the Delete button, and the app sets the labels and images in that cell accordingly. The row is not deleted, it is just updated, as you normally do with static cells (assign outlets and access them like other static content).

**Edit:**
Also check out the `performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe` property of the `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` class in iOS 11. Set it to `true` to allow the full swipe gesture, no need to install a recognizer of your own.

You did mention iOS 10 Mail; I don’t know if or how Apple does it in iOS 10 since this property is an iOS 11 feature. Also iOS Mail very likely has a table with dynamic content.

Answer (score -1):

You simply have to add these functions and change them to your desired needs.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         }
```

and this

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let example1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "example1") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: IndexPath!) -> Void in
            //  run your desired action
        }

        example1.backgroundColor = .white

        let example2 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "example2") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: IndexPath!) -> Void in
            //  run your desired action
        }

        example2.backgroundColor = .green

        let example3 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "example3") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: IndexPath!) -> Void in
            //  run your desired action
        }

        example3.backgroundColor = .orange

        return [example1, example2, example3]

    }
```

Comment: this is not the answer for the question

Comment: He says he doesn't want a button, just swipe to delete.